# emacs windows, distribute the width through the frame

Tags: emacs

I used once a very nice emacs function that set all my windows (emacs windows, not frames) width evenly.

If you open emacs and do `C-x 3` twice in a row, you get three vertical windows. Then running the function I am looking for makes the width of these windows the same.

I can't for the life of me find this function again.
Wouldn't someone help me to:

- find the name of the function
- give me the keyboard shortcut if any
- tell me what I should have done to find the answer by myself

Thanks!

Comment: What I did was a bit tedious, but I basically hit M-x and did tab complete.  It opened a new buffer and I just skimmed through the numerous functions looking for something that looked useful.  There's definitely got to be a better way though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're looking for <kbd>M-x</kbd> `balance-windows`.

Comment: Correct!
Thanks for the fish!
I'd like to learn fishing, though.

Comment: `C-h w FUNCTION-NAME RET` will tell you the keybinding (if any) once you know the function.  The answer is left as an exercise to the reader.  `C-h a REGEX RET` will search the commands for the regular expression.  In particular `C-h a window RET` would have been useful.  And don't forget my personal favorite `C-h k` which will tell you what command is run when you press a particular key (together with `C-h l` you can figure out what you just did when something weird happens).

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I wonder if I didnt't try `C-h a`, but missed the balance window. A shame.